# Ansible not performing a simple "yum install"

Tags: ansible, yum

New to Ansible, so apologies if this is a really simple answer.  Trying to get an Ansible script working.  For some reason I can't get the Ansible script to do a simple yum install of a package on the host's base repository:

ie: in my `tasks/main.yml` for my role I have the following excerpt:

```
     - name: simple_test_install
       yum: name=top state=installed
```

(note, I have tried **"latest"** and **"present"** to no avail)

The output I get is similar to this:

```
    TASK [role-name : simple_test_install] ***********************************
    fatal: [ansible_hostname_url]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "No Package matching 'top' found available, installed or updated", "rc": 0, "results": []}
```

I go on the client and the package is available through yum...What could be the problem?  Why is it not installing?

Comment: "I go on the client and the package is available through yum" I don't believe you.

Answer (score 4):

It's giving you the answer right here:

```
No Package matching 'top' found available, installed or updated
```

Maybe the package you are looking for is `procps`, `htop` or `mtop`?

A useful command is:

```
yum whatprovides *bin/top
```

Run that on your target host, and you can see the packages that provide `top`